# Maven will not execute tests

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit

I have a default Maven directory structure, but it will not see/run my tests. The directory structure is as followed:

```
src
    -main
        -java
            -com.foo.webservice
                -...
    -test
        -java
            -com.foo.webservice
                -AbstractTest.java
```

When I run the command `mvn test`, it tells me nothing, but a successful build.

The project is viewable on my Git over [here](https://github.com/TisLars/fenrir-service).

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class AbstractTest {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO dao;

    @Test
    public void testGetCustomer() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setUsername("JUnitCustomer");
        customer.setCompanyName("SpringTest");
        customer.setPhoneNumber("0612345678");
        if (customer != null) {
            assertNotNull("Username isn't null", customer.getUsername());
            assertNotNull("Company isn't null", customer.getCompanyName());
            assertTrue(customer.getPhoneNumber().length() == 8);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCustomerPhoneNumber() {
        assertTrue(dao.getCustomer(0).getPhoneNumber().length() == 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tunaki It was indeed the 'abstract' part. I also found out that your class name can not contain 'abstract', so I removed the abstract part and made it a `public class UnitTest`. Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code, the class you want to test with JUnit is `abstract`.

However, for JUnit to run your test, your class must not be `abstract`. You should declare your class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
    }

}
```